# ROBLOX | Unions flying toward origin point for no reason?

Tags: roblox

I am trying to make a wander script that randomly picks orientations and distance to walk, and i am using the tweenservice to make it look smooth. For some reason all the parts the script is in keeps flying back to 0,0,0. Here is my script:

```
while true do
wait(math.random(1,10))
--turn
local tweenService = game:GetService("TweenService")
local part = script.Parent

local tweeningInformation = TweenInfo.new(

1.5, 
Enum.EasingStyle.Linear, 
Enum.EasingDirection.Out, 
0,    
false, 
0  
)

local partProperties = {
Orientation = script.Parent.Orientation + Vector3.new(0,math.random(1,180),0)

}

local Tween = tweenService:Create(part,tweeningInformation,partProperties)
Tween:Play()
wait(1.5)
--move



local tweeningInformation2 = TweenInfo.new(

1.5, 
Enum.EasingStyle.Linear, 
Enum.EasingDirection.Out, 
0, 
false, 
0  
)

local partProperties2 = {
Position = script.Parent.CFrame.lookVector * math.random(5,50)
}

local Tween = tweenService:Create(part,tweeningInformation2,partProperties2)
Tween:Play()
wait(1.5)
```

end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the new position you are using the lookVector which is an unit vector, you should use the actual position of the part.

```
Position = script.Parent.Position + (script.Parent.CFrame.lookVector * math.random(5,50))
```